# Is there a way to use AS3's Sound Object methods on an FLV

Tags: actionscript-3, flv, waveform

I'm recording and playing back mic input using Flash Media Server, and even though it's just audio, we're saving the output as FLV. I'd like to get a waveform of the recorded audio. Ideally, since we already have a lot of saved/recorded audio, I'd like something that can take a loaded FLV and get the waveform, as opposed to generating it at record or playback time.

AS3 has the new Sound.extract() method that can be used for this (plenty of online tutorials), but it seems like it only works for MP3. Is there a way to use this method on FLV audio? Or is there another to extract a waveform from a FLV? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SoundMixer.computeSpectrum to generate a global snapshot of sound that is currently playing.

The return data is a ByteArray containing some audio information

The Adobe´s documentation link below has more details:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#computeSpectrum()

Hope it helps!